# Vagrant up not working, it requires a manual fsck

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vagrant, fsck

My setup:

- My OS is Ubuntu 18.04
- Vagrant 2.0.0
- VirtualBox 5.2.18 r124319
- Ubuntu installed into vagrant/virtualbox (version uknown)

`sudo vagrant up` was always working, suddenly it has stopped working... it gets stuck on `SSH auth method: private key` until reach timeout.

So I run `sudo vagrant up` with GUI enabled to check for errors, and what I found:

```
Scanning for Btrfs filesystems 
/dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root: contains a file system with errors, check forced. 
/dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root: Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.

/dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.  (i.e., without -a or -p options) 
fsck exited with status code 4 
The root filesystem on /dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root requires manual fsck
```

How to proceed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've solved the issue. Here is how:

- `vagrant up` with GUI enabled
- As soon as GUI open, keep pressing Right Shift, select "Advanced Options for Ubuntu" and then select "Ubuntu in Recovery mode"
- After "/dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY" appears, run `fsck /dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root` pressing Enter everytime the proccess ask to fix an issue
- `vagrant up`again with GUI disabled, problem solved

Comment: This solutions works but I wonder if anyone knows a way to prevent this from happening? We have developers hitting this issue multiple times a week and it's pretty tedious to constantly fix.

Comment: @OwenAllen This issue usually occur when the VM doesn't exit propperly (such as bruteforcing stop your computer with power button, without `vagrant halt` or closing your process.